# How can the current build context directory be referenced inside of a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to set an environment variable to the current build directory inside of a Dockerfile. For example, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
ENV APP_SRC $BUILD_CONTEXT # Save the current host directory to an env variable
COPY . /$APP_SRC           # Copy the app source code to a directory of the same name in the container
```

I know it sounds like a weird thing to do, but I need my directory name to be the same in the container as it is on my host machine. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With docker 1.9, you can pass [build-time environment variable](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14634#issuecomment-155572446):

```
docker build --build-arg APP_SRC=$BUILD_CONTEXT -y tag .
```

`$APP_SRC` will then be valued like `$BUILD_CONTEXT`.

Note that this is not yet supported by docker compose: both [issue 2111](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2111) and [2163](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2163) are asking for that feature.

Comment: I was considering doing something like that, but I can't figure out how to do it with docker-compose. Is there a way to include a build-arg in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @KevinCraft this is not yet supported by docker compose. I have edited the answer to make that clear.